# Sound output limiter to prevent volume spikes on a Linux desktop?

Tags: linux, audio, chrome, streaming, audio-volume

Is there a way to prevent sudden sound spikes in Chrome browser like those caused by streaming TV commercials?

I've Googled for a solution to this but the only thing I've found is a Windows utility named [Sound Lock](https://www.3appes.com/sound-lock/).  Something like this would be a useful solution, but I'm open to suggestions.